# Trying to install subclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, subclipse, subversive

I went through all the steps with eclipse indigo, and I can't seem to get subclipse to install in my version of eclipse.  Well, at the very least, I don't see it anywhere.  What am I doing wrong?
[image: My current version of eclipse sans subclipse... Where is it?]

I can't install subversive either?  The link won't show up when I put it into the add dialogue box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the install process completed then it is likely installed.  What are you expecting to see?  Look in your Eclipse preferences under Team > SVN.  If you see that, then it is installed.